# Rails sign-up form on home page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I seem to see questions on how I would be able to have my sign-up form for Users on the main page (static_pages#home) using devise, but couldn't find one for using just Rails.

I have this as my form on my home page:

```
  <h2>Sign Up</h2>
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <br>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %><br>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %><br>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm password" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %><br>

      <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
```

However, when I submit the form, the user data does not get saved (for some reason, the attributes of email and passwords are not taken from the form entries). I have instantiated the @user variable in the home action, so I'm not sure why this does not work.

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
    def home
        # For future where sign-up page is on home page.
        @user = User.new
    end
end
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would **highly** recommend using Devise. Handling user authentication is tricky business, especially trying to keep things secure.

Second, you need to have a controller action for the user to be saved. Something like:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @user.save!
  end
end
```

And then add the right route to your `config/routes.rb` file.

Comment: You're right, though I wanted to try it without Devise to learn the ropes first. So that controller action in StaticPages does not seem to solve it. It seems as if the form is going straight to the Users Controller where it uses the 'create' action there and never touches the one in StaticPagesController. Somewhere between it seems as if the attributes are lost? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the form target action by explicitly passing an url to it, doens't necessarly need to by the default #create action in UsersController.

So you could try that along with @Judy's answer

Comment: Oops, stupid me. I was using Strong Parameters and in my create action, I had @user = User.new(params[user_params]) instead of just User.new(user_params). Dumb question on my part. But for anyone else, good to know that it works fine with the default create action in the UsersController.